# Send List to new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Im trying to send a List to next activity 
the list

List mGF = new ArrayList();

i cant figur it out...  i have read and try for days...

Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ViewImages.class);
i.put....? (mGF);

How do i send and how do i get it as mGF in the next activity

hope you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried this but thought the questions was interesting.. so I went searching

In the Intent [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) there are quite a few different ArrayList type put??extra methods.
Depending on the type of your ArrayList you should use one of them.

ex

```
ArrayList<String> mGF = new ArrayList<String>();

Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ViewImages.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("package prefix"."whateverYouWannaNameIt",mGF);
```

Then you use getStringArrayListExtra("package prefix"."whateverYouWannaNameIt")

I fell over this when I was looking around for some solutions for your [problem](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/88862755c2a3d4de) that might help.

Comment: Thanks! got it working!
Just added (ArrayList<String>)
i.putStringArrayListExtra("com.packageprefix",(ArrayList<String>) mGF);